# Vue component not rendered inside router-view

Tags: scope, components, vue.js, vue-router

recently I've been using vue in frontend and vue-router with it to shape a SPA.

My problem is that I am not able to access a component defined in main Vue instance:

```
import ElementComponent from './Element';

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   components: { Element: ElementComponent }
});
```

Whenever I do `<element></element>` within the #app scope the component gets rendered but I can not use the element inside a route component.

My routes are defined like this:

```
var routes = [
{ path: '/section/part', component: require('../views/Part') }];
```

And then provided to router instance:

```
 new VueRouter({routes});
```

Breakpoint whenever I try to call `<element></element>` inside Part component template I get this in vuedevtools: *[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
(found in  at C:\Users\Doe\project\js\views\Part.vue)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the component into the `views/Part` component. So do the same thing that you did in the main Vue instance, but only in the part component.

I believe if you want to make components global you need to do use

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
})
```

reference https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration

Comment: Okay, I am giving it a try in instance

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, global components indeed